# Should I do Contract.Ensures for any method result?

Tags: c#, code-contracts

Let's say I have this one:

```
[Pure]
public static TimeSpan Seconds(this int i)
{
    Contract.Ensures(Contract.Result<TimeSpan>() == TimeSpan.FromSeconds(i));
    return TimeSpan.FromSeconds(i);
}
```

Is that right that I ensure the contract result in such strict way, or it is unneccessary?

---

And in this case?

```
[Pure]
public static T IfTrue<T>(this bool b, T value)
{
    Contract.Ensures(Contract.Result<T>().Equals(b ? value : default(T)));
    return b ? value : default(T);
}
```

---

My questions are:

1. Am I right when indicating such precise contract ensurance?
2. Am I obligated to make such strict contract ensurances and why?
3. Is it okay, that my contract ensurance repeats (in many cases in my application) the `return` statement?

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: I'm learning `Code Contracts`.

Comment: This looks like a good practice gone too far. Avoid.

Comment: Here, you're testing that the `return` keyword in C# actually works. Seriously? You should test for specific values, and even then, in such a trivial method, it would be pointless.

Comment: @Baboon I'm actually pointing to the code-contracts tools what value will this method return so it could be more well formed about inner variables and not to throw out stupid warnings. Am not I right?

Comment: Look at [Damien's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13417529/677014), those contracts make sense.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Think about the word "Contract" - what do you, in writing your code, wish to *guarantee* to your callers (or for `Requires`, what do you want them to *guarantee* for you).

For trivial examples such as the ones you've shown, I can't think of much you'd want to include as a *contract*. Maybe for the first, I'd go for:

```
[Pure]
public static TimeSpan Seconds(this int i)
{
    Contract.Requires(i>0);
    Contract.Ensures(Contract.Result<TimeSpan>().TotalSeconds > 0.0);
    return TimeSpan.FromSeconds(i);
}
```

I'll guarantee to my callers that I'll produce a positive result. Obviously, this similar contract could be given if I included more complex mathematics inside this method. I'll give guarantees on the range, but I won't guarantee exactly how the result is computed (since that may be subject to change).

Answer (score 0):

Method purity means, that method call does not causes any caller visible side-effects to object state. *That's all*.

Of course, pure method can be public, and can define its own pre- and post-conditions. It depends on concrete method use-cases.

Comment: The question is more about `Contract.Ensures` usage. Could you please tell me is that method neccessary have to be there, or not, and why?

Comment: @AgentFire: *what* method and where's *there*? If you mean, is `Contract.Ensures` necessary in `[Pure]` methods, that the answer is "no". Can `Contract.Ensures` be placed in `[Pure]` methods? Yes. When `Contract.Ensures` can be placed in `[Pure]` methods? It depends on concrete method purposes.